# Keep service alive in parallel task in ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, task-parallel-library

I have a ASP.Net Core Web API using EF Core for database interaction.
DBContext life cycle is managed per Dependency Injection container in startup class:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(opts =>
                opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString")));
```

In a web GET method, I want to use a background task which process and save data into database but the DBContext is disposed before using it for saving data.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(int id)
    {
        var item = _context.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);

        Task t = new Task(() => SaveAsync(_context));
        t.Start();

        return Ok(item);
    }

    private void SaveAsync(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //processing something for a while
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

The problem is that _context object has been disposed by DI container and I get the error below:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.'

The error is perfectly clear for me but do you know a mean to keep alive the _context in background task?

Comment: Why don't you do `await _context.SaveChanges()` in `Test`? `Test` already is async.

Comment: Are you wanting `public MyController(MyDbContext context)` to always return the exact same object?  If so, did you register `MyDbContext` as a singleton?

Comment: @GertArnold The purpose was to send the result ASAP to the client. In my case, the SaveChanges method inserts 100000 rows in database. With await, the result won't be returned to the client before the SaveChange completion which can take very long time.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns That could be a solution but the piece of code above is a simplification of my project which is already in production and setting MdDbContext as a singleton could bring more complication and unexpected behaviour.
Moreover, in my production code, I use Repository pattern of which the classes are already disposed.

Comment: Then I would look at your DI container to see if it's providing the incorrect object under load.  I know Lamar has an issue that returns the wrong object under very high loads at a significant % of the time.  https://github.com/nathansoz/LamarScopedRepro

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like that, I recommend you look into [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). However, to get around this error try using [RegisterForDispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.registerfordispose?view=aspnetcore-3.0). There is also an async version.

```
HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(_context);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think IHostedService could be the most sustainable solution in my case. I can create a HostedService having a queue of tasks and put my long process and saving as a task in the queue